# Crash after a deletion in a tableView and pop the animated view. Another iOS7 SDK bug?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, crash

I have a monstrous problem with Xcode5.

There is a tableView with data from NSUserDefaults

When I delete a row from TableView everything works fine but if you come back using my navigation back button to the super view app crashes!

Also the super view does not have any special. Its just 4 buttons in screen.

Here is some of my codes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [reminders removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:reminders];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arr forKey:@"reminders_Key"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [_table reloadData];


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post any crash log/information, also add a `Exception breakpoint` in the breakpoint pane.

Comment: app crashes in assembly codes 0x2f78:  calll  0x2bd4a2                  ; symbol stub for: UIApplicationMain
0x2f7d:  movl   %eax, -16(%ebp)   // here app stops!
0x2f80:  movl   -52(%ebp), %eax
0x2f83:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x2f86:  calll  0x2bdb4a                  ; symbol stub for: objc_release

Comment: please post the error from the debugger, this looks like unsymbolised crash report and is not telling us enough to go on.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Here is the debugger error : Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5000000c) One more thing: When I get back to superview using new interactivePopGestureRecognizer the app does not crash but using navbar back it crashes! Note: it only crashes when you delete a row from tableview and then press nav bar button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

After using Apple Zombie Profiler instrument I found the reason of the crash.

It was because ARC deallocates the view in this situation by mistake.
So I just allocate the view again before any pop animation for preventing this crash.
something like this before in my pop function:

self.view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];